# ¿Qué es variable de clase y una variable de instancia?

Tags: java, variables

Buenas a toda la comunidad. He escrito este *POST* con el objetivo de mejorar el entendimiento sobre **variable de clase y de instancia**. He buscado por Internet, y lo que me ha quedado claro, es que:

1. Una variable de clase lo es cuando es escrito como **static**,lo cual, se declara en campos como **static** en constructores y métodos. Además, las constantes de clase sería **static final**.
2. Una variable de instancia no lleva nada en especial, solo que se crea como objeto, se instancia ese objeto y se utiliza en un método, en ese orden.

No sé si lo he interpretado bien o si me falta algo más por saber o entender y si he interpretado bien lo que he escrito antes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cuando declaras variables estáticas en una clase puedes acceder a ellas desde cualquier parte sin crear un objeto de él. Por ejemplo:

```
public class Persona{
  static public String nombreEstatico = "Nombre Estatico";
  public String nombreMiembroClase = "Nombre Miembro de la clase";
}
public class Main{
  static public main(String[] args){
  System.out.println(Persona.nombreEstatico);
  Persona persona = new Persona();
  System.out.println(persona.nombreMiembroClase);}}
```

Las variables estáticas las llamas con el nombre de la clase y un punto, y el nombre de la variable o función.
Para acceder a variables del objeto (las no estáticas), deberemos instanciar un objeto de él y acceder a su variable o función.

Answer (score 8):

Primero es necesario precisar que la especificación del lenguaje Java 
es bastante exacta en los términos que usa, y en particular la palabra **miembro** no es usada. Hablamos siempre de **variables** que *pertenecen* a una clase, a un objeto o a un método.

Remitiéndonos a la [especificación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3) encontramos lo siguiente:

> Existen ocho tipo de variables:
>
> 1. Una *variable de clase* es un campo declarado usando la palabra reservada `static` dentro de una declaración de clase o con o sin la palabra reservada `static` dentro de una declaración de una interfaz. Una variable de clase es creada cuando su clase o interfaz es preparada y es inicializada a un valor por defecto. La variable de clase deja de existir cuando su clase o interfaz es descargada.
> 2. Una *variable de instancia* es un campo declarado dentro de la declaración de una clase sin usar la palabra reservada `static`. Si una clase `T` tiene un campo `a` que es una variable de instancia, entonces una nueva variable de instancia `a` es creada e inicializada a un valor por defecto como parde de cada nuevo objeto creado de la clase `T` o de cualquier clase que sea subclase de `T` La bariable de instancia deja de existir cuando el objeto del cual es campo deja de ser referenciado, después que cualquier finalización necesaria del objeto ha sido completada

Las variables de clase le pertenecen a la definición de la clase. Para definir una se hace uso de la palabra clave `static` como modificador.

```
public class Car {

    public static int total = 0;

    public Car() {
        total++;
    }

    public static int getTotal() {
        return this.total;
    }
}
```

La variable `total` es compartida por **todos** los objetos de tipo `Car` que se creen:

```
Car carro1 = new Car(); //total=1
Car carro2 = new Car(); //total=2, la variable se comparte en todas las referencias
System.out.println(carro1.total); //Imprime 2
System.out.println(carro2.total); //Imprime 2
```

Cada vez que creo un objeto de tipo `Car` aumento en uno la variable `total` (cantidad de objetos creados), ya que la variable es compartida por todos los objetos (porque pertenece a la definición de la clase), cua
En principio uno podría pensar en una variable de clase como una 'variable global. Ya que la definición de la variable le pertenece a la clase, es posible acceder a la misma sin necesidad de usar una referencia a un objeto, por lo que esto es absolutamente válido:

```
System.out.println(Car.total);
```

accedemos a la variable a través del *nombre* de la clase y no de alguna referencia a un objeto.

Las variables de instancia son aquellas que se declaran en una clase pero *sin* la palabra reservada `static`

```
public class Book {

    private int total = 0;

    public Book() {
        total++;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return this.total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

}
```

A diferencia de las variables de clase, la propiedad y responsabilidad de estas le pertenece a cada objeto que se cree. Por ejemplo:

```
Book libro1 = new Book(); //la variable total de esta referencia es 1
Book libro2 = new Book(); //la variable total de esta referencia es 1 y NO es la misma que la variable total de la referencia libro1
```

Dicho de otro modo, las variables de instancia son responsabilidad de cada *instancia* de una clase, por lo que cada una tiene su propia copia de la variable y modificar el valor de una variable de instancia en el objeto `libro1` no modificará el valor de la misma variable de instancia con el mismo nombre en el objeto `libro2`

```
libro1.setTotal(10); //Al modificar la variable de instancia total en la referencia libro1 sólo modifico la copia de esta
System.out.println(libro1.getTotal() == libro2.getTotal()) //Imprime false, ya que son variables diferentes.
libro2.setTotal(8); //De igual modo, al modificar la variable de instancia total en la referencia libro2 tampoco modifico la variable del mismo nombre en la referencia libro1 porque son variables diferentes.
System.out.println(libro1.getTotal() == libro2.getTotal()) //Imprime false, ya que son variables diferentes.
```